# Make a PayPal donation anonymously

Tags: paypal

I'd like to make an anonymous PayPal donation. Is it possible? 
If not, what if I make a PayPal payment using my credit card directly (i.e. not logged in with an account)? Does it show up as anonymous in that way?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into the "guest" payment option..

Comment: Which is what I was referring to in my question. What I'd like to know is, would this include the credit card's owner name, or would it be anonymous, at least to the payment receiver?

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke with Paypal about this (Jim)4/4/14, and he said they do have a proposal for that, that they will be voting on, where you could use a nickname or some such thing to anonymize donations or payments.

He said if I added my request for it, it would pump up the proposal's chances of succeeding. So anyone with a paypal account, please give them a call and request it if you want to see them eventually do that.

Paypal 888-221-1161